# How do I use one element of an XNA Spritefont file in another?

Tags: c#, xml, xna

Looking to have a parent `Spritefont` named `regular` and have it's "children", `bold` and `italic` use the same `<Style>` attribute.

So instead of the `<Style>` line (ln ~40ish) in a default `SpriteFont` file, you'd have something like this that is supposed to pull the `<Style>` from `defaultFont.spritefont`:

```
<Style><xi:include href="defaultFont.spritefont" xpointer="xpointer('//Style')" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude"/></Style>
//instead of 
<Style>Bold</Style>
```

Unfortunately, I get a `Style is missing error` whether or not I erased the `<Style>` line, which leads me to believe that either XNA looks for exactly a `<Style>regular/bold/etc<Style>` line or that my substitution isn't working correctly.

What do I need to do so that my C# XNA project project will allow me to use an element from one `Spritefont`'s xml file in another, before I compile it?

Comment: What's the reason for this, If you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Joe Convenience really. I would like to only have to change one file instead of 3 or 4 that are all bold/italic etc variations of one base font. I looked into it more, and I think I'll have to build either a new `ContentImporter/Processor` to allow XNA to read element content as method rather than string. Decided that was too complex for such a small change. Am writing a python script to change the files manually instead.

Comment: You'd probably need to write a content pipeline extension to get this working "nicely".

Comment: I don't know if this is useful to you. The Vector Fonts can be scaled, it no depends on the font size. http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Vector%20Fonts&referringTitle=Home